# How to Compare a User's Input with the text length of a paragraph in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

I been trying to create an app that will compare the user's answer to the number of letters in a sentence.

It always comes up "No“ when guessed correctly.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p class="cat">cat</p>
        <form id="Form">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number" id="guess" value="">
            <button type="submit" >Get Value</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="apps.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
let form = document.getElementById("Form");
let guess = document.getElementById("guess").value.length;
let cat = document.querySelector('.cat').textContent.length;    

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let result;
     if (cat === guess){
        result= "yes";
    } else {
        result= "no";
            
     } 
        console.log(result);  
        return  result;
        
    });
```

Comment: Your input's value's length is evaluated before the form is submitted. It should be evaluated upon submission.

Comment: Unrelated naming/conceptual issue: I would not call the length of a string `cat` (same with `guess`). Maybe grab the element and calc the length as needed (as the answers indicate) or use the variable name to make what it is explicit. This makes it easier to think about the code.

Comment: Yeah, That's a good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're evaluating the length of your input before the form submission, as well as you're comparing the length of your input with the length of the `.cat` value, rather than parsing the input as an integer and comparing it with the length of `.cat`.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("Form");

const cat = document.querySelector('.cat').textContent.length;

const guess = document.getElementById("guess");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const result = (parseInt(guess.value) === cat)?("yes"):("no");
  
  console.log(result);  
  
  return result;
});
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="cat">cat</p>
    <form id="Form">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number" id="guess" value="">
        <button type="submit" >Get Value</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried parsing it before but I ended up also doing it before the submission so it came out with the same result

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate the length of the input when submitting the form. You will also need to parse the value of the guess as an integer, before you compare it to the length of the phrase.

```js
const phrase = document.querySelector('.phrase');

document.forms['guess-form']
  .addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const
      guess = e.target.elements.guess, // e.target === form
      isValid = parseInt(guess.value, 10) === phrase.textContent.length;
    console.log(isValid ? 'yes' : 'no');
    return isValid;
  });
```

```html
<p>Phrase: "<span class="phrase">cat</span>"</p>
<form name="guess-form">
  <input type="number" name="guess" placeholder="Enter length of phrase" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```